# How to resolve error for ListIterator in android?

Tags: android, list

I am using List object to store data to sqlite 
while storing it i am getting error for NoSuchElement

here is my code

```
public void saveOrderDtls(List<OrderDtls> odrDtls, SQLiteDatabase db)
        throws SQLException {

    try {
        System.out.println("List size Dao::"+odrDtls.size());
        //for (OrderDtls odtls : odrDtls) {

         ListIterator<OrderDtls> litr = null;
         litr=odrDtls.listIterator();
         while(litr.hasNext()){              
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("cr_usr",litr.next().getCrUsr() );
                values.put("cr_ts", litr.next().getCrTs().toString());
                values.put("eat_ordr_id", litr.next().getEatOrdrId());
                values.put("eat_mst_stk_item_id", litr.next().getEatMstStkItemId());---Error here at this line
                values.put("ordr_qty", litr.next().getOrdrQty());
                values.put("ordr_unit", litr.next().getOrdrUnit());
                System.out.println("litr.next()::"+litr.next());                    
                db.insertOrThrow("eat_ordr_dtls", null, values);

                db.setTransactionSuccessful();                  
          }
         } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        ise.getStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

I checked value for "eat_mst_stk_item_id " by printing `List<OrderDtls> odrDtls` list 
in activity it self is has value but still giving me error at `eat_mst_stk_item_id`, which is String type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `litr.next()` wrongly. Each time you call `next()` the `litr` will move to the next item.

From the official documentation the [next](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) method

```
Returns the next object in the iteration.
```

So at some point your `while` loop will try to get an item beyond the size of `litr` and you will end up getting a `NoSuchElementException`

Instead get the item at the start of the loop like this

```
while(litr.hasNext())
{              
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  OrderDtls currentItem  = litr.next();

  values.put("cr_usr",currentItem.getCrUsr() );
  values.put("cr_ts", currentItem.getCrTs().toString());
  values.put("eat_ordr_id", currentItem.getEatOrdrId());
  values.put("eat_mst_stk_item_id", currentItem.getEatMstStkItemId());---Error here at this line
  values.put("ordr_qty", currentItem.getOrdrQty());
  values.put("ordr_unit", currentItem.getOrdrUnit());

  System.out.println("litr.next()::"+currentItem);                    


  db.insertOrThrow("eat_ordr_dtls", null, values);

  db.setTransactionSuccessful();                  
}
```

You will need to replace the `litr.next()` with your `OrderDtls` object.

Comment: Thank Apporv ..Can you just tell me one more ..I am getting List size 3 but it shows System.out.println("litr.next()::"+currentItem);  for two times

Comment: Can you check in the database if 2 or 3 values are stored? Because everything else looks fine.

Comment: I am entering 3 values but its storing only 2 and not giving any error

Comment: Sorry everything looks fine in this snippet. Maybe you should try to debug and check it.

Comment: @AditiK Did you find the problem?

Comment: I solved it by changing call line db.setTransactionSuccessful(); after for loop now its working